# tsconfig.json: types file works when in 'files', but not in 'include'

Tags: typescript, build, tsconfig

In my TypeScript project I'm extending express Request type to add own properties. I have a file `src/types/index.d.ts` that looks similar to this:

```
declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
  interface Request {
    customFlag?: boolean;
  }
}
```

Part of my `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "./server.ts"
],
```

When I'm runnning the project, it crashes on `req.customFlag` usage (says that property does not exist for type).
If I modify my `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "./server.ts"
],
"files": [
    "src/types/index.d.ts"
],
```

it starts to work smoothly.

Why is that? My understanding of TS docs is that `include` and `files` are interpreted the same way, the only difference is that the first allows to specify patterns.

If I run `tsc --listFiles --noEmit`, the result contains `src/types/index.d.ts` for both configs. Yet for the first one it's not working.

Comment: Could you add your `tsconfig.json` here?

Comment: Are you trying to augment the types in the `@types/express-serve-static-core` package? If so, you aren't doing that properly.

Comment: I would guess that order is important and the second config loads `src/types/index.d.ts` first.  If you really wanted to you could confirm that by setting a breakpoint `src/types/index.d.ts` and another in your file where `req.customFlag` is used, and checking which gets triggered first in each configuration.

Comment: By any chance do you have [`skipLibCheck`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck) options set to `true`?

Answer (score -1):

I think the expression `src/**/*.ts` is just not fitting to the two dots in the filename `index.d.ts`.

So you might rename the file to include only one dot or try to adjust the expression.
**This is just an example**, assuming that you might want to include all files with one or two dots in the filename, **it might be utterly wrong**:
`src/**/*?.?*.ts`

The important page in the documentation is about [include](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include).